# How can I find $\theta$ when converting an equation to cylindrical coordinates?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, analytic-geometry

> The equation is $x^2+y^2=4y$ and I need to convert it to cylindrical coordinates

Here is what I did:

$x = 2r\cos(\theta)$

$y = 2r\sin(\theta)$

$2r^2\cos^2(\theta)+2r^2\sin^2(\theta) = 4\sin(\theta)$

$2r^2(\cos^2(\theta)+\sin^2(\theta) = 4\sin(\theta)$

$2r^2=4\sin(\theta)$

$r^2=2\sin(\theta)$

$r=\sqrt{2\sin(\theta)}$

If the above is correct, how do I solve for $\theta$?

Comment: Your third equation is wrong.

Comment: @YvesDaoust oh.. should it be $4r^2cos^2(\theta)+4r^2sin^2(\theta)= 4sin(\theta)$

Comment: This is still wrong, put your glasses on.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I see now.  I need to drop the coefficient $4$ from the terms on the left side of the equation.  I was told, in a previous thread, that I had to put a multiplicative coefficient on the terms since (in this example) $cos^2(\theta)+sin^2(\theta)=1$ and in my example it's $4$ to make the statement true.

Comment: Fix completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some mistakes in your derivation.

[Cylindrical coordinates](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CylindricalCoordinates.html) are given by:
$$
x=r\cos \theta \qquad y=r\sin \theta \qquad z=0
$$
so your equation $x^2+y^2=4y$ becomes:
$$
r^2\cos^2\theta +r^2\sin^2\theta=4r\sin \theta
$$
$$
r=4\sin \theta \qquad or \qquad \theta=\arcsin (r/4)
$$

Comment: A circle diameter 4 tangent to x-axis going through the origin.

Answer (score 1):

The correct solution was given, but this is also solvable in Cartesian coordinates. Rewrite

$$x^2+y^2-4y+4=x^2+(y-2)^2=4.$$

This is the equation of a circle centered at $(0,2)$, with radius $2$. It passes through the origin.